# How i can covert json string to html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How i can convert below json data to html table element in page?

[MY JSON DATA URL](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDEUR%22%2C%20%22USDJPY%22%2C%20%22USDBGN%22%2C%20%22USDCZK%22%2C%20%22USDDKK%22%2C%20%22USDGBP%22%2C%20%22USDHUF%22%2C%20%22USDLTL%22%2C%20%22USDLVL%22%2C%20%22USDPLN%22%2C%20%22USDRON%22%2C%20%22USDSEK%22%2C%20%22USDCHF%22%2C%20%22USDNOK%22%2C%20%22USDHRK%22%2C%20%22USDRUB%22%2C%20%22USDTRY%22%2C%20%22USDAUD%22%2C%20%22USDBRL%22%2C%20%22USDCAD%22%2C%20%22USDCNY%22%2C%20%22USDHKD%22%2C%20%22USDIDR%22%2C%20%22USDILS%22%2C%20%22USDINR%22%2C%20%22USDKRW%22%2C%20%22USDMXN%22%2C%20%22USDMYR%22%2C%20%22USDNZD%22%2C%20%22USDPHP%22%2C%20%22USDSGD%22%2C%20%22USDTHB%22%2C%20%22USDZAR%22%2C%20%22USDISK%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=)

my data every time come from this url and i can't define static json data in page or script !

i want to create simple table in page when page load and read data from url...

Comment: Where is the attempted code you did?

Comment: Read the JSON, then [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=JSON.parse) it and finally create a table using [HTMLTable Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This Ajax Approach:

```
var url="https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDEUR%22%2C%20%22USDJPY%22%2C%20%22USDBGN%22%2C%20%22USDCZK%22%2C%20%22USDDKK%22%2C%20%22USDGBP%22%2C%20%22USDHUF%22%2C%20%22USDLTL%22%2C%20%22USDLVL%22%2C%20%22USDPLN%22%2C%20%22USDRON%22%2C%20%22USDSEK%22%2C%20%22USDCHF%22%2C%20%22USDNOK%22%2C%20%22USDHRK%22%2C%20%22USDRUB%22%2C%20%22USDTRY%22%2C%20%22USDAUD%22%2C%20%22USDBRL%22%2C%20%22USDCAD%22%2C%20%22USDCNY%22%2C%20%22USDHKD%22%2C%20%22USDIDR%22%2C%20%22USDILS%22%2C%20%22USDINR%22%2C%20%22USDKRW%22%2C%20%22USDMXN%22%2C%20%22USDMYR%22%2C%20%22USDNZD%22%2C%20%22USDPHP%22%2C%20%22USDSGD%22%2C%20%22USDTHB%22%2C%20%22USDZAR%22%2C%20%22USDISK%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=";


var $tbody = $('#table').find('tbody');
var $thead = $('#table').find('thead');
$.ajax({
url: url,
}).done(function(data) {
    var ObjectKeys=Object.keys(data.query.results.rate[0]);
    var row="<tr>";
    $.each(ObjectKeys, function (i, key) {
        row+="<th>"+key+"</th>";
    });
    row+="</tr>";
 $thead.append(row);

$.each(data.query.results.rate, function (i, el) {
    $tbody.append($('<tr />').append($('<td />').text(el.id)).append($('<td />').text(el.Name)).append($('<td />').text(el.Rate)).append($('<td />').text(el.Date)).append($('<td />').text(el.Time)).append($('<td />').text(el.Ask)).append($('<td />').text(el.Bid)));
});

})
```

[**Working Fiddle Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/47qrxjrr/5/)

Answer (score 3):

Heres a simple solution catered to your needs

```
var $tbody = $('#table').find('tbody');
var $thead = $('#table').find('thead');

$thead.append($('<tr />').append($('<th />').text('id')).append($('<th />').text('Name')).append($('<th />').text('Rate')).append($('<th />').text('Date')).append($('<th />').text('Time')))

$.each(data.query.results.rate, function (i, el) {
    $tbody.append($('<tr />').append($('<td />').text(el.id)).append($('<td />').text(el.Name)).append($('<td />').text(el.Rate)).append($('<td />').text(el.Date)).append($('<td />').text(el.Time)))
})
```

Where data is your JSON

https://jsfiddle.net/6rcmw7cm/2/

Answer (score 1):

You if you don't want to use external JS libraries, then you can simply iterate through the array and build a table.
Here is the example which builds a table for your needs.

First, you need to create a table DOM element:

```
var table = $("<table/>"); // create a table HTML DOM element
```

Let's start filling the table with header:

```
var headerTr = $("<tr/>"); // let's create a header row

// header is build on keys of response objects. you can use your own
for (var headerKey in obj.query.results.rate[0])
{
    $("<td/>").text(headerKey).appendTo(headerTr); // append a cell to the header row
}

table.append(headerTr); // apppend the header row to a table
```

Now, it's time to fill data rows:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.query.results.rate.length; i++) // iterate through items
{
    var item = obj.query.results.rate[i];

    var tr = $("<tr/>"); // create a row
    for (var key in item)
    {
        $("<td/>").text(item[key]).appendTo(tr); // append cells to a row
    }

    table.append(tr); // append row to a table
}
```

We have completed the table! Now, we only need to append it to our document body:

```
$("body").append(table);
```

Here is the [working JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xsggupod/3/).

I hope that using jQuery is OK for you. If it is not, then you can *easily* transform this code to vanilla JS.